# How to Initialize Integers + String Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, delimiter

I'm new to C++ and need help! I'm currently learning how to do 2D arrays or just 1D arrays.

I have a text file with the following contents shown below, and I'm basically trying to store them into an array or more depending? Is it true that I can have just 1 Array if I use Struct, or 5 individual Arrays based on the contents in the file below?

I believe that the [1, 2] can be formed into a 2D Array, but how do I go about implementing it?

Below are my codes for using a struct, and I'm not sure if I did it right?

Please help!

```
=========================================================
Sample Contents in 'HelloWorld.txt' File
=========================================================
[1, 2]-3-4-Hello_World
[5, 6]-7-8-World_Hello
[9, 1]-2-3-Welcome_Back
[4, 5]-6-7-World_Bye
[8, 9]-1-2-Bye_World

=========================================================
My Sample Codes
=========================================================
struct Example()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("HelloWorld.txt");

    vector<string> abc; 
    string line;

    while(getline(file, line, '-'))
    {
        abc.push_back(line);

        int** a = new int*[abc.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < abc.size(); i++)

        cout << abc[i] << endl;

        delete [] a;
    }
}
```

My main objective is to be able to store all the 4 integers + 1 string into arrays, and learn how to create a 2D array with the '[1, 2]' -> the first two integer points.

Awaiting advice! Thank you!

Comment: C++ don't have 2D arrays. It has arrays (and sometimes arrays of arrays)

Comment: @Wilmort Yes I created this file. Its similar to my lecture notes. Testing it out so I created this sample text file.

Comment: @JustaGreenie it is very complicated you can write these even with spaces and you can easily parse it. But If your lecture requires this file then you need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

First, use c++ features and data structures. You can use vector instead of array it is more safe and easy to use. Second you do not have to use 2D array you can use 1D array that is vector. Our data structure is vector of your struct vector you can read file and create a struct with these values and then put in the vector.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct MyData
{
    MyData():
        num1(0),
        num2(0),
        num3(0),
        num4(0),
        str("")
    { }

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
    std::string str;
};


void ReadFile(std::vector<MyData>& myVec)
{
    std::string fileName = "HelloWorld.txt";
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios::binary);

    if (file.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Error while reading";
        perror(fileName.c_str());
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        //parse this line
        // store suitable values to the struct
        // MyData myStruct;
        // myStruct.num1 = ...
        // myStruct.num2 = ...
        // myStruct.num3 = ...
        // myStruct.num4 = ...
        // myStruct.str = ...
        //myVec.push_back(myStruct);
        // or you can directly use emplace_back that is more efficent
        // but is more complicated for you now..
        // you can practice...
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyData> myVector;
    ReadFile(myVector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Referring to your codes:
MyData myStruct;
myStruct.num1 = ...
myStruct.num2 = ... //(what codes usually go here? is it for initialising?)

Comment: Yes, initializing with the values from file.

Comment: I have managed to initialized my file so that it has removed all the delimiters ('-', '[', ']'). and have used stringstream to read the integers from the string lines in file.

so now the file output will be:
1
2
3
4
Hello_World
5
6
7
8
World_Hello
.
.
.

however, I'm still unable to store it in an array! Please advise anyone!

Comment: You can now.. 
1 2 3 4 Hello_World 
5 6 7 8 World_Hello
Create file like that. Every line has 4 integer and 1 strings. Spaces are separator. So you can store first 4 item as an integer and last one as a string..